# All of my questions have already been asked!

Tags: discussion, promotional-grant

So my Diablo 3 game just arrived (Thanks SE!), and I'm keen to jump into asking all the questions I have about the game.

The only problem is, since I received the game so late (shipping to Aus is a pain) all of the questions I've had have already been asked.

Normally I wouldn't have this problem, because there are a tonne of questions you can ask about a game, but seeing as [diablo-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3)is already the number 5 tag on the site, I feel like we're starting to run out of possible questions.

Seeing as I need to ask 8 questions (of which I've already asked 2 before I even got the game) or I won't be able to join the running for the next Game Giveaway, I really would like to ask some questions.

What should I do in this situation? Should I purposely hunt out questions which may be of low quality?

I understand if I just have to resign to the fact that I probably won't be able to participate in the next giveaway (unless I actually come across a problem, or 6, that no-one else has asked).

Comment: In my opinion, if Gaming.SE giveaways are used to sponsor QAs for a new released game there is a problem here. It is of course not your fault MrSmooth, but I suggest to reconsider to go for a digital key only giveaway next time, in order to avoid delivery problems.

Comment: Don't forget that the contest counts *posts* for qualifying, which means Answers count too. I didn't realize this at first, and thought the contest was only for questions :)

Comment: I feel your pain @MrSmooth, I'm leveling all my chars in sync, so I haven't reached high enough levels yet to really run into any problems that require me to ask questions. But like the rest said, just keep chugging along!

Comment: @Rachel - Are you sure about that?  Reading the original post regarding the giveaway, it says: "Requirements: All you have to do is ask 8 questions about your new game within the first 2 weeks of playing it. If you fulfill your commitment, you’ll be eligible for the next round (eligible, not guaranteed). If not, no worries - you just sit the next round out, but will still be eligible for future rounds."

Comment: @Shinrai I'm sorry, I thought this question was about the Diablo3Acts contest, and didn't realize there was also a promotional grant going on. That comment is invalid here :)

Comment: The bright side of me not winning a free copy of D3 is that I don't have to spend time asking/answering questions and can just play the game :P

Answer (score 12):

I'm always surprised how many more good questions can be asked at a point where I thought that we should have run out of questions long ago. I started the ME3 contest later due to the european release date, but that wasn't by far as much a problem as I thought, I easily managed to ask the eight questions required for the grant.

There's still a large amount of possible content where we have only scratched the surface, e.g. we have hardly any questions about the inferno difficulty. I'm convinced that there are still hundreds of quality questions that can be asked, without having to scrape the bottom of the barrel.

Answer (score 6):

Play the game. Experiment. Explore the systems and subsystems of the game. See if there are things that you don't understand or don't know that are not yet asked. Keep the scope of your questions narrow enough to avoid overlap with existing questions and to allow yourself to ask multiple related questions.

You shouldn't bother asking low quality questions because they will be removed if the quality is too low or the questions too trivial.

You can also just give up on the next giveaway contest. You've already won one so let someone else have a fair crack at it.

To be honest, I don't like your chances of coming up with 6 questions. The reason the questions have been asked is because they aren't *yours,* but are obstacles that are faced by everyone who plays the game and if any are non-trivial, someone will likely ask about them. The giveaway contest *really* doesn't help your situation. Trying to come up with new questions for that since even 24 hours after the launch of the game internationally has been hard and we're all in the same boat.

I don't think using the giveaways to sponsor QAs for new releases is entirely kosher, especially coupled with a second giveaway contest to further sponsor QAs, but my thoughts on this really don't matter and never did -There *are* a lot more questions and answers so I can't really argue with the results. Next time you consider participating, you'll either have to plan on foregoing the subsequent giveaway, elect to use a more expedient delivery method, hope that more luck is with you then or simply give up on participating.

Answer (score 6):

As @skovacs1 says, do your best to explore and come up with some questions. Of course, we understand that shipping may prohibit you from fulfilling the 8 question commitment and won't be mad at you for it! I can't bend the rules and allow you into the next game grant, but this is why we reinstate eligibility for future rounds. It's nice to spread the free games around anyway in my opinion, so don't worry too much about it. If you don't get to ask the 8 questions, just sit out the next round and feel free to enter the one after that :-)

In the future, hopefully we'll be able to gift digital downloads so this won't be a problem. I'm really sorry that this wasn't possible for this round.